# MySQL Workbench - Modify database tables with records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to modify tables of a database that I did with MySQL Workbench, this database has several tables and all tables have user information, thousands of records.

Can I change this database with records from MySQL Workbench and then export all the changes again with all the amendments and records?

The changes I want to do is add new additional fields to some tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to add plus fields (columns?) you can do them without any export or import needed with either MySQL Workbench or SQL queries.

MySQL change table: [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Or in MySQL Workbench right click on the table than click Alter table... Add the new columns than click Apply, this will add the new columns without hurting any already added data. You can also specify the default value.

Comment: Thank you very much, great, but I also keep editable file ".mwb" MySQL Workbench, which is visible all table relationships that previously did before exporting the database or "forward engineering" This can be done?

Comment: Sure, Click "Database" in the menu and select "Reverse Engineer" you can connect to your modified database and reverse engineer it to a database model so you will have an .mwb from your most up to date database and you can delete the old one.

Comment: This step already have done, but this option allows for the database with its structure and model, but the records of the database does not take them, it can be done in a way that all existing records will bring in the database, so they can be available the next time we have to do the forward engineering.

Comment: The DB structure and data are two different things. After you modified the database and done with reverse engineering you can go to 'Server' -> 'Data Export', select your database and all tables in it. Select the file you want to save the data and click Start Export. This will create an executable SQL file that can recreate your database tables and all data in it if you need it.